# Iptables url filltering

Tags: iptables, webserver, url, restricted-access, jboss

i have a web app and i want to filter the access like this:
block incoming connection to http://my-ip:8080/
access incoming/outgoing to http://my-ip:8080/the-rest-of-the-address
actually i want to block the access to my web server but not the application
this does not work and drop it all.

```
sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp –dport 80 -m string –string “Host: http://my-ip:8080/” –algo kmp -j DROP
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not understanding why you don't simply block access to port destination port 8080. Use of the `string` module is a burden on the CPU. Please explain the difference between your application and your web server.

Comment: my web server in jboss
i need to access jboss for some configuration actually i want to limit the access to web server
my web server open like this : http://my-ip:8080/
and my web app open like this : http://my-ip:8080/the rest of address

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Webserver you're using, .htaccess files might help you out if you'd like to restrict access to certain folders and you're using Apache.
In the document root you may create a .htaccess that permits any access attempts.

(see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867576/deny-access-to-all-folders-except-a-few-ones-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp –dport 8080 -m string –string “Host: http://my-ip:8080/the-rest-of-the-address” –algo kmp -j ACCEPT
sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp –dport 8080 -m string –string “Host: http://my-ip:8080/” –algo kmp -j DROP
```